# Pointer and memory issue in c

Tags: c, pointers

I have a C program that outputs two different strings and concatenates them.
The Second output, both `s` and `t` are the same thing but, the third one, they're different.
Why is this? I think it has something to do with the way they are declared as pointers but I am not sure.

Comment: What? Did someone remove the code? Why? The question makes zero sense now, and the answers even less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward.

```
char *s = t;
```

Initially `s` points to `t` so they are in fact the same buffer. Any string operations on either one affect the same memory and hence printing either one out gives the same result.

But then you change where `s` points to.

```
s = (char*) malloc( 100 );
```

From that point on `s` and `t` are independent. That is, point to different memory locations. So from that point on any string operation you do on one has no effect on the other. Hence when you `strcat` to `s` the contents of `t` do not change.

BTW, your code is not protecting against buffer overflows. I'll assume that's just because this is test code. But always good practice to guard against that.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy( t, "on the footsteps of dawn" )` obliterates `t` and the contents of the array become "on the footsteps of dawn".  It remains this way for the rest of the program's execution.  You never modify `t` after that.  `s` doesn't point to t after the `s = malloc(100)` line.

P.S.  Never use `strcpy`.  `strncpy` is safer, but still not that safe because it may not append a null character to your buffer.  `snprintf` is your friend.  It always appends a null byte and your program would be a whole lot shorter if you used it.